# How do I keep results filtered with new results added dynamically?

Tags: angularjs

I'm using an infinite scroller package which loads results dynamically.  I have a set of filters which display the results I want depending on what filter is selected.

The results will not be returned to the front end in any sort of filtered order.  What I want to achieve is get the unfiltered results being returned into filtered state that I may already have selected.

For example one filter is a star rating and lets say that I have 3 and 4 star selected in my filter.  How would I get newly loaded results to be returned within that filter.

I suppose I could send the filters back to the backend to specifically request what I'm looking for but I'm looking for an angular solution.

Here's the `ng-repeat` that iterates over each hotel I want any newly loaded results to be subjected to any filters already selected:

```
<div ng-repeat="hotel in (filteredHotels = (hotelResults |  hotelRatingsFilter:ratings)) | startFrom:(currentPage - 1)*10 | limitTo:10 " class="hotel-results-container">
  <ul>
   <li>{{hotel.starRating}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This is the code that communicates with the backend, as far as I can tell (I didn't write it)

```
.constant('HOTEL_SEARCH_CONSTANTS',{
    httpSettings:
    {
        url:'/hotel/hotelsearch/search',
        method:'POST'
    }
})



.service('hotelSearchService',     ['CachedObservable','$http','HOTEL_SEARCH_CONSTANTS','HOTEL_CONSTANTS','baseSearchSettings','loadingScreen',
   function(CachedObservable,$http,HOTEL_SEARCH_CONSTANTS,HOTEL_CONSTANTS,baseSearchSettings,loadingScreen){
CachedObservable.call(this)
var _this = this,
    p

this.search = function(searchParameters){
    var config = HOTEL_SEARCH_CONSTANTS.httpSettings
    var currentSearch = angular.extend(searchParameters,baseSearchSettings)
    config.data = {
        basicSearch: baseSearchSettings,
        hotelSearch: searchParameters
    }

    _this.update(p=$http(config), angular.extend(angular.copy(searchParameters),baseSearchSettings) )
    //Alert subscribers with both the promise and the search parameters
    //used

    loadingScreen.newSearch.update(p,HOTEL_CONSTANTS.loadingTemplates.loadingMessageTemplate)
    //Trigger a loading screen and specify the template to use
}

}])
```

Thank you

Comment: can you show some code that you have

Comment: I've added the ng-repeat code, I'm not sure what else would be useful.  If I can provide anything else that would be of use, please ask :)

Comment: the $http part of getting the data and setting, share that code as well, that would also be helpful

Comment: Are you getting all the rows in a single request? Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: I'm getting the first 10 rows on the first request, the next 10 on the next request etc.

Answer (score 0):

I found this article that says that angular will iterate over the array if there is any change to the data.  Looks like its safe to keep adding to the data array and any filters already being used will be applied by angular to the updated data array.

Step 6 says:

"A watch is added on the array, which triggers step 1 again if the array undergoes any change"

[ng-repeat in angular](http://www.befundoo.com/blog/optimizing-ng-repeat-in-angularjs/)